# MissingPluginException captureScreenshot Screenshots iOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am trying to automate screenshots using the integration test library. I get the error

```
flutter: The following MissingPluginException was thrown running a test:
flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method captureScreenshot on channel
flutter: plugins.flutter.io/integration_test)
```

I found a workaround here
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91668

To add change IntegrationTestPlugin.m

```
+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar> *)registrar {
    [[IntegrationTestPlugin instance] setupChannels:registrar.messenger];
}
```

While this works I have the issue that our CI will overwrite changes to Library code. Is there a way to check a change like this into Git so that the Library bug can be included in the checked-in code